# Requiring something in entire Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mixpanel

I want to require 'mixpanel-ruby' so that I can use it anywhere in my Rails app, but I'm not sure which file it should go into.

Comment: Try the `application.rb` file.

Comment: after you put it in the gemfile where is it not working? I don't think you need to require it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new `.rb` file in the `/config/initializers/` folder and initialize MixPanel from there, like this:

```
MixPanelTracker = Mixpanel::Tracker.new(YOUR_MIXPANEL_TOKEN)
```

Then, you can call `MixPanelTracker` from any place in your app.